# Add Imagelist to ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to make an application that displays my skype contacts with their avatar next to their name. However, I cannot seem to get the avatar to show

Below is the method that is supposed to add it to the ListView:

```
foreach (Tuple<User, string, string, string> a in list)
{
    imageList1.Images.Add(GetUserImage(a.Item1.Handle));
    listViewEx1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(a.Item1.Handle, imageList1.Images.Count - 1)
    {
        SubItems = {a.Item1.FullName, a.Item2, a.Item4 }
    });
}
```

And here is the method that grabs the image:

```
string app = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Skype\\Avatars\\";
public Bitmap GetUserImage(string SkypeID)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(app) == false)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(app);
    }
    dynamic command0 = new SKYPE4COMLib.Command();
    command0.Command = string.Format("GET USER {0} AVATAR 1 {1}", SkypeID, app + SkypeID + ".jpg");
    s.SendCommand(command0);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return new Bitmap(app + SkypeID + ".jpg");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure the view on you listview supports the image list, also set listview.Imagelist to you imagelist and check that this images aren't empty or null. I didn't know they had computers in whiterun though, must be some dwemer shit.

Comment: Assuming the images do get loaded ok: Did you set `imageList1` as the `listViewEx1.LargeImageList` ? -  Also:  Do yourself a favor and add the `SkypeID` or the image name as the `Key` property (1st param in the `Add` overload) so you can access the images better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late for the OP but might help others with similar symptoms: the `ImageList` instance is populated with images and correct keys, the `ListView` instance is populated with items with the correct `ImageKey`, and the images work fine in a `PictureBox`, but the `ListView` just **won't display the images**.

The cause appears to be that setting the `SmallImageList` or `LargeImageList` performs some kind of copy rather than holds a reference. If you change the contents of the `ImageList` *after* you have set `SmallImageList` or `LargeImageList`, the changes will not be displayed in your `ListView`.

The answer is to set `SmallImageList` and/or `LargeImageList` to the `ImageList` instance again if you make any changes to them.

[NB I haven't worked through the cause properly; I have just found that this answer solves this symptom]